# Getting data twice on page in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have my theme page.php as:

```
<?php /* The loop */ ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?> >
        <header class="entry-header">
               <div class="hd"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ! post_password_required() ) : ?>
                <div class="video"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="hd"><?php //the_title(); ?></div>
        </header><!-- .entry-header -->     
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links"><span class="page-links-title">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentythirteen' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>', 'link_before' => '<span>', 'link_after' => '</span>' ) ); ?>
        <!-- .entry-content -->
        <footer class="entry-meta">
            <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentythirteen' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
        </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
    </article><!-- #post -->
    <?php // comments_template( '', true ); ?>      
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

And I have made three page in wordpress blog, image and news and i also assigned them category for each. now i have installed  **php-exec plugin** . Now I am writing some php code in page editor to retrieve blog data...

It working fine but it fetching data twice and now got it is becouse of page.php .

**So can i have some condition on page.php if i am trying to fetch some data by cotegory then page.php data would not be display...**

here is my code which i applied on blog page editor

```
<?php if (query_posts('cat=63&showposts=5')) : ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        // do whatever you want
    ?>
    <div class="gallery_views"> 
        <div class="hd"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
        <?php // get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        <?php // cup_post_nav(); ?>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <?php comments_template(); ?>
        <b><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></b>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: add this in query_posts('post_type' => 'page') page.php above while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php if (query_posts('cat=63&showposts=5')) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  // do whatever you want
?><div class="gallery_views"> 
 <div class="hd"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
<?php // get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
                <?php // cup_post_nav(); ?>
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                <?php comments_template(); ?>
<b><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
<?php
break;
endwhile;
?>
<?php else : ?>
```

Add a break in your while, it'll stop after the first loop.

Comment: I added a break in the While loop, this will "break" the loop and just grab one result. Your loop was getting 2 posts and that's why it was showing 2 instead of one :)